# PIR motion detector or Emitter receiver pair or?

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, infrared, motion

I have a simple 3 ft by 3 ft goal. I want to electronically detect when a ball passes into the goal but not when it goes wide.

I had initially thought i could use a simple PIR motion detector pointing downward  on the cross bar but I am concerned that 
1) it might detect balls that go wide? (how do i restrict the arc)
2) it might be too slow for a fast moving ball
3) it might miss balls in top corner etc

Option two is a series of emitter reciver ir pairs on each side of the goal post. Enough to make sure that a ball can't get through. See attached sketch of the options.

I have zero experience with this. I am thinking the emitter pairs is best option but I am unsure? Maybe there is another alternative? The overriding concern is that the solution must require minimal power to run (and cost!).

[image: options]

edit as directed by site to explain why not duplicate -- to reiterate my comment below:
yes they are similar questions. I think my question was more specific. I asked specifically for option a) or option b) or something else. Steve G kindly informed me *why* the PIR was not suitable -- as it uses temperature -- as opposed to use solution this because i think so. For this reason I think this question is worthy as a standalone and I will update the answer to reflect why PIR was not suitable.

Comment: I'm not sure that a PIR will detect a football. A PIR detects a difference in temperature between a moving object and the background. That works well when the object is a person, who usually will be hotter than the background, but a football would be about the same temperature as the background. It is also quite small so doesn't give off a lot of IR radiation anyway.

Comment: I just noticed that you said the goal was 3' x 3' so presumably the ball is smaller than a football. That makes it less likely that a PIR motion detector will work. I suggest you look at [Goal Line Technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goal-line_technology)

Comment: Hi @SteveG thanks for the replies. Yes it's 3ft by 3ft goal but i do intend using standard size 4/5 footballs to start. Based on you're 1st comment re: temperature this might be a moot point anyway and the emitter/receiver pairs look like best option. thanks again

Comment: hi @ChrisStratton, yes they are very similar. I think question was a bit more specific. option a) or option b) or something else. Steve G kindly informed me why the PIR was not suitable -- as it uses temperature -- as opposed to use this because i think so. For this reason I think this question is worthy as a standalone and I will update the answer to reflect why PIR was not suitable. I am open to discussion too etc as I am not fully au fait with procedure re: duplicates and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just to officially post an answer to this question, reposting what @SteveG said above in the comments, a transmitter receiver pair is the most suitable option.

A PIR is  deemed unsuitable as it

> detects a difference in temperature between a moving object and the background

and as such is unsuitable to detect an object that is likely to have a similar temperature to the ambient temperature